# MS-DOS debug -l 0 not working

Tags: debugging, dos

I want to write a bin file to a flash drive. I'm supposed to run:

```
n helloworld.bin
l 0
w 0 0 0 1
```

But when I run `l 0` I get a `File not found` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `helloworld.bin` does not seem like a valid MS-DOS 8.3 filename.

Comment: I changed it to "helloworld" (without an extension) and it still doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions. The bin file is a custom bootloader create from "nasm -f bin -o helloworld.bin helloworld.asm"

Comment: `helloworld` also isn't a valid MS-DOS filename in 8.3 format.  And are you *really* on an MS-DOS box?

Comment: I compiled using nasm on a Unix box

Comment: Well, last time I used MS-DOS debug was some 15 years ago, so my knowledge has become a bit rusty.  MS-DOS filenames should have a maximum of 8 letters before the dot and a maximum of 3 letters after the dot.  Furthermore, I'd simply use `l` to load the file instead of `l 0`, but I might be wrong about this...

Comment: You are correct! It works fine now! Please put an answer so that I may give you credit. But I am getting a "Disk error writing drive E" when I try to execute the "w 0 0 0 1" command. Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- MS-DOS filenames should have a maximum of 8 letters before the dot and a maximum of 3 letters after the dot.
- For this use of the `l` command in debug, provide no parameters.  The file will always be loaded to `CS:0100`.

(I somehow find it worrying that my brain saved this useless information for all those years...)

Comment: I am getting a "Disk error writing drive E" when I try to execute the "w 0 0 0 1" command. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @Mohit: That's probably somehow related to an access restriction of your Unix enviroment, though I'm puzzled by the drive letter E.  You provided 0 as drive index, which should be drive A.

Comment: Why are you using debug for this anyway?  Wouldn't it be simpler to use `dd` in your Unix environment?